# Running a Databind method from jquery keypress method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, data-binding

I have a simple page where a repeater is populated by a c# databind method. The page has a search textbox that i want to search as you type. This works via the rowfilter in the databind method filtering by what is in the searchtextbox.

i have jquery triggering on each keypress but want it to run my c# databind method on each keypress. How can i do this?

Databind Method

```
protected void DataBindVideosRepeaterList()
    {
        DataView dv = (DataView)IRPAdminHelpTopicVideoDB.GetAllVideos();
        dv.RowFilter = this.GetVideosFilter();

        this.RptVideos.DataSource = dv;
        this.RptVideos.DataBind();
    }
```

RowFilter Method

```
protected string GetVideosFilter()
    {
        string filterCriteria = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TxtVideoSearch.Text))
        {
            filterCriteria = " Tags LIKE '%" + this.TxtVideoSearch.Text + "%'";
        }

        return filterCriteria;
    }
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#TxtVideoSearch").keypress(function () {

/** I WANT THE DataBindVideosRepeaterList() METHOD TO RUN HERE **/

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a hidden dummy button to the page that has a click event that will trigger `DataBindVideosRepeaterList()`.

```
<span style="display: none">
    <asp:Button ID="DummyButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</span>
```

Now when the keypress is triggered, simulate a button click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= TxtVideoSearch.ClientID %>").keypress(function () {

        $("#<%= DummyButton.ClientID %>").click();

    });
</script>
```

Then a PostBack will occur and the method is run

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBindVideosRepeaterList();
}
```

However I would recommend triggering the filter on the `blur` or `focusout` event of TextBox `TxtVideoSearch` or a separate button click. Because now there is a PostBack on every keypress and the site will not function properly towards the user.

Comment: Good thinking. what if i was to put it all in an update panel and added the button click as a trigger. would this work?

Comment: Yes that would be better. Then there will not be a page refresh.